# Spring Content(1.2.5) JPA maximum file size limitation(Postgres)

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-content-community-project

Does *Spring Content* have some limitations regarding file size in PostgreSql? I tried to save 7,4 GB file, works well. But which type is used under the hood, how much data we can save per file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Content JPA detects the database type from the connection and chooses an appropriate BLOB API to use.

In the case of PostgreSql it uses the Large Object API.  As such we are constrained by their [limitations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127409)